# Why does a monitor connected through a DVI-to-VGA connector goes black when booting?

Tags: windows, boot, external-display, windows-xp, connector

I have a Galaxy GF9500GF PCI-e video card, 1GB. It has two DVI ports and I connect it to a VGA cable using a special connector. When Windows XP SP3 is loading (I can see the progress bar), the monitor goes black. Why is this happening? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried the other DVI port? You might be connected to the secondary output.

Comment: Does the screen stay black?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's just the driver loading into the kernel and the adapter "resetting". You should make sure you're running the latest drivers, but I have seen that flicker on almost every machine I've dealt with, it's just an aspect of booting, the screen flickers, no big deal.